# How I can calculate a pointer base address in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have a pointer like below:

```
char *p=malloc(94)
```

After a lot of search around base pointer address calculation, I find this solution:

```
e = log(size)

size = 1 << e

base = p & ˜(size-1);
```

How does this formula work? Can anybody explain this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Prerequisites:**

This instruction:

```
size = 1 << e;
```

Means shifting 1, e bit to the left that is equivalent to `1 * (2^e)`.

In this instruction:

```
base = p & ˜(size-1);
```

`p & ˜(size-1)` means doing binary and (&) between p and the unary complement of size (`(size-1)`).

**Example:**

```
allocation space
------------
|          | 0001 1111
------------
|     .    |
|     .    |
|     .    |
------------
|          | p = 0001 0100
------------
|     .    |
|     .    |
|     .    |
------------
|          | 0001 0000
------------

e = log(16) = 4

size = 1 << 4 = 0001 0000

size - 1 = 0000 1111

~(size -1) = 1111 0000

base = 0001 0100 & 1111 0000 = 0001 0000
```